# How do I get an Hp Scanjet 2300c working?

Tags: 11.10, drivers, hp, support

After i connect my HP Scanjet 2300c, Ubuntu 11.10 won't detect it. I have searched for a driver in the internet but i still haven't found any compatible driver for the Scanjet 2300c.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)